# Однородные члены и разное управление

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, управление, однородные-члены

*Клиент зачастую покупает не саму услугу, а **предотвращение** или **спасение от** нежелательного будущего.*

Есть всем известная ошибка — нарушение нормы синтаксической сочетаемости при употреблении однородных членов, а именно использование одной управляемой формы при однородных членах. В случае выше оба однородных членах требуют после себя существительного в родительном падеже, однако второй однородный член ещё требует предлога "от" — является ли это уже разным управлением: родительный падеж без предлога и с предлогом? Правомерно ли такое употребление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oбщее зависимое слово допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа **и предлога**.

> **Предотвращение** или спасение **от нежелательного будущего**.

Это ошибка. Сравните у Розенталя: "руководство и контроль за распределением гуманитарной помощи".

> [§205. Управление при однородных членах предложения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)
>   При двух или нескольких управляющих словах общее зависимое слово допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и предлога, например: читать и конспектировать книгу; подбирать и готовить кадры; протравливать и яровизировать семена; надеяться и рассчитывать на помощь.
>
> Наличие общего зависимого слова при различном управлении нарушает грамматико-стилистическую норму, например: «с помощью и в сотрудничестве с местными организациями» (ср. правильный вариант: с помощью местных организаций и в сотрудничестве с ними), «организация и руководство стачечной борьбой»; «в соответствии и на основе утвержденного плана»; «надеяться и верить в возможность»; «руководство и контроль за распределением гуманитарной помощи».